# Android - Kotlin with Dagger2, lateinit property component has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm a Dagger new and I get the following error using it.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                      Process: com.biolabsalta.app, PID: 8028
>                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.lab.app/com.lab.app.ui.login.LoginActivity}:
>   kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property
>   component has not been initialized

This error happened when I passed my project from java to kotlin.
Sharing my code. Please help

**ActivityComponent.kt**

```
@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = arrayOf(ApplicationComponent::class),
        modules = arrayOf(ActivityModule::class))
interface ActivityComponent {

    @ActivityContext
    fun context(): Context

    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)

    fun inject(activity: LoginActivity)

    ...
}
```

**ActivityModule.kt**

```
@Module
class ActivityModule constructor(private val activity: AppCompatActivity) {

    @Provides
    @ActivityContext
    fun provideContext(): Context = activity

    @Provides
    fun provideActivity(): AppCompatActivity = activity

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    fun provideMainPresenter(
            presenter: MainPresenter<MainMvpView>): MainMvpPresenter<MainMvpView> = presenter

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    fun providerLoginPresenter(
            presenter: LoginPresenter<LoginMvpView>): LoginMvpPresenter<LoginMvpView> = presenter
...
}
```

**BaseActivity.kt**

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MvpView {

    lateinit var activityComponent: ActivityComponent

    override val isNetworkConnected: Boolean
        get() = NetworkUtils.isNetworkConnected(applicationContext)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        activityComponent = DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
                .activityModule(ActivityModule(this))
                .applicationComponent(LabApp.component)
                .build()
    }
```

**LoginActivity.kt**

```
class LoginActivity : BaseActivity(), LoginMvpView {

    @Inject
    lateinit var presenter: LoginMvpPresenter<LoginMvpView>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        activityComponent.inject(this)

        presenter.onAttach(this)

        btn_login.setOnClickListener{
            presenter.onServerLoginClick(account_email!!.text.toString(),
                    account_password.text.toString())
            hideKeyboard()
        }
```

**LabApp.kt**

```
class LabApp : Application() {

    companion object {
        lateinit var component: ApplicationComponent
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(ApplicationModule(this))
                .build()

        component.inject(this)
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
I just forgot to declare in the manifest.

```
android:name=".LabApp"
```

Comment: Try to remove `component.inject(this)` from `LabApp`

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know anything about dagger but

You are calling

```
presenter.onAttach(this)
```

When `LoginMvpPresenter<T>` is not yet initialized.

```
@Inject
lateinit var presenter: LoginMvpPresenter<LoginMvpView>
```